# Navigating a grid

Tags: python, algorithm, navigation, grid

I stumbled upon a problem at Project Euler, https://projecteuler.net/problem=15
. I solved this by combinatorics but was left wondering if there is a dynamic programming solution to this problem or these kinds of problems overall. And say some squares of the grid are taken off - is that possible to navigate? I am using Python. How should I do that? Any tips are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lattice paths algorithm does not finish running for 20 X 20 grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342710/lattice-paths-algorithm-does-not-finish-running-for-20-x-20-grid)

Comment: You can find some interesting solutions for Project Euler problems if you check out their forums. For example, for this one, about halfway down the page there's a solution in Ruby using dynamic programming. So this at least confirms that the same is possible in Python, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a mathematical solution (which is probably what you used):

```
def factorial(n):
  result = 1
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    result *= i
  return result

def paths(w, h):
  return factorial(w + h) / (factorial(w) * factorial(h))
```

This works because the number of paths is the same as the number of ways to choose to go right or down over `w + h` steps, where you go right w times, which is equal to `w + h choose w`, or `(w + h)! / (w! * h!)`.

With missing grid squares, I think there is a combinatoric solution, but it's very slow if there are many missing squares, so dynamic programming would probably be better there.

For example, the following *should* work:

```
missing = [
  [0, 1],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0],
]

def paths_helper(x, y, path_grid, missing):
  if path_grid[x][y] is not None:
    return path_grid[x][y]

  if missing[x][y]:
    path_grid[x][y] = 0
    return 0
  elif x < 0 or y < 0:
    return 0
  else:
    path_count = (paths_helper(x - 1, y, path_grid, missing) +
                  paths_helper(x, y - 1, path_grid, missing))
    path_grid[x][y] = path_count
    return path_count

def paths(missing):
  arr = [[None] * w for _ in range(h)]
  w = len(missing[0])
  h = len(missing)
  return paths_helper(w, h, arr, missing)

print paths()
```

Comment: Thought you already had it :D. The solution you mentioned is indeed the same one I used; now all that's left is the elimination.

Comment: @Kurns My answer has been edited to include elimination.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple backtrack and explore an implicit graph like this: (comments explain most of it)

```
def explore(r, c, n, memo):
    """
        explore right and down from position (r,c)
        report a rout once position (n,n) is reached
        memo is a matrix which saves how many routes exists from each position to (n,n)
    """

    if r == n and c == n:
        # one path has been found
        return 1

    elif r > n or c > n:
        # crossing the border, go back
        return 0

    if memo[r][c] is not None:
        return memo[r][c]

    a= explore(r+1, c, n, memo)    #move down
    b= explore(r, c+1, n, memo)  #move right

    # return total paths found from this (r,c) position
    memo[r][c]= a + b

    return a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n= 20
    memo = [[None] * (n+1) for _ in range(n+1)]

    paths = explore(0, 0, n, memo)
    print(paths)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most straight-forwardly with python's built-in memoization util [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). You can encode missing squares as a `frozenset` (hashable) of missing grid points (pairs):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def paths(m, n, missing=None):
    missing = missing or frozenset()
    if (m, n) in missing:
        return 0
    if (m, n) == (0, 0):
        return 1
    over = paths(m, n-1, missing=missing) if n else 0
    down = paths(m-1, n, missing=missing) if m else 0
    return over + down

>>> paths(2, 2)
6
# middle grid point missing: only two paths
>>> paths(2, 2, frozenset([(1, 1)]))
2
>>> paths(20, 20)
137846528820
```

Comment: Thanks. The question only remains how do I eliminate the missing squares, but thanks for the cache tip! I will certainly keep that in mind.