# Is this tail recursive and could it cause a stack overflow? C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I am wondering why the first way I get a VS/Resharper note that the tail recursion could be replaced with a loop, and I did indeed manage to get something similar to cause a stack overflow so I read up on how tail recursions work and how it grows the stack etc.

This first one generates the tail recursion note.

```
    private static string GetLine()
    {
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        if (s == null)
        {
            return GetLine();
        }
        return s;
    }
```

But doing it like this does not:

```
    private static string GetLine()
    {
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        if (s == null)
        {
            s = GetLine();
        }
        return s;
    }
```

So my question is; is the second one not considered tail recursive, ie it cannot create a stack overflow because it does not generate all the stack calls?

Comment: You got it backwards, *tail recursion* won't generate stack overflows, but a non-tail recursive call can.

Comment: In any case C# does not guarantee that even when tail-call optimization *can* be done, it actually *is* done. So it can create a stack overflow anyway (it will also actually happen, except sometimes on x64)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, naive [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) *will* generate a stack overflow, unless an operator exists in the system (and is properly used) to optimize for that scenario.  The CLR does have such an opcode (`tail`).  C# does not have a vehicle for leveraging that opcode reliably.

Comment: @KirkWoll AFAIK RyuJIT doesn't need the `tail` prefix and generates a loop nonetheless (see my answer), but there's no guarantee, as the x86 version shows.

Comment: @Kirk, C# proper (i.e. us) may not have that vehicle, but *the compiler* has it, and can decide to use it depending on the context it's operating on. It's actually better and safer that way.

Comment: @KirkWoll See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571052/2884172  Release/x64 or Release/AnyCPU does use tail recursion. x86 or Debug modes do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usr explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37768926/3764814), ReSharper tries to find known patterns in your code it can offer refactorings for.

But let's take a look at the generated code for both cases.

---

The first function:

```
private static string GetLineA()
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();

    if (s == null)
    {
        return GetLineA();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Gives this (x64, Release):

```
00007FFB34AC43EE  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FFB34AC43F0  sub         rsp,28h  
00007FFB34AC43F4  call        00007FFB8E56F530  // <-- Console.ReadLine
00007FFB34AC43F9  test        rax,rax  
00007FFB34AC43FC  jne         00007FFB34AC440F  
00007FFB34AC43FE  mov         rax,7FFB34AC0F60h  
00007FFB34AC4408  add         rsp,28h  
00007FFB34AC440C  jmp         rax  
00007FFB34AC440F  add         rsp,28h  
00007FFB34AC4413  ret
```

You can clearly see it's tail recursive, since the only `call` instruction is for `Console.ReadLine`.

---

The second version:

```
private static string GetLineB()
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();

    if (s == null)
    {
        s = GetLineB();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Gives this:

```
00007FFB34AC44CE  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FFB34AC44D0  sub         rsp,28h  
00007FFB34AC44D4  call        00007FFB8E56F530  // <-- Console.ReadLine
00007FFB34AC44D9  test        rax,rax  
00007FFB34AC44DC  jne         00007FFB34AC44E3  
00007FFB34AC44DE  call        00007FFB34AC0F68 // <-- Not good.
00007FFB34AC44E3  nop  
00007FFB34AC44E4  add         rsp,28h  
00007FFB34AC44E8  ret
```

There's a second `call` there, so you don't get tail recursion, and the stack *will grow*, eventaully leading to a stack overflow if it grows large enough.

Well, it looks like the JIT didn't optimize the code into a tail recursive call.

---

Anyway, beware, since you're at the mercy of the JIT.

Here's `GetLineA` in x86:

```
00F32DCA  in          al,dx  
00F32DCB  call        72A209DC  // <-- Console.ReadLine
00F32DD0  test        eax,eax  
00F32DD2  jne         00F32DDC  
00F32DD4  call        dword ptr ds:[12B8E94h]  // <-- Ouch
00F32DDA  pop         ebp  
00F32DDB  ret  
00F32DDC  pop         ebp  
00F32DDD  ret
```

See? You can't really depend on it, and the language provides no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper just does not detect the second form. It doesn't try hard. Program analysis is hard and impossible in general (see the halting problem). Resharper mostly has a few nice and helpful heuristics.

If you replace `ReadLine` with `null` you'll see that a stack overflow is very possible here.