# Recursive Method Puts Strain on UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, backgroundworker, sendkeys

I have a method that utilises `SendKeys.Send`, waits for a few seconds using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` and then runs another method to check the colour of a pixel to see if it has changed. The method then runs again as it is called recursively.

This method needs to be able to run thousands of times before stopping. The Winform's UI seems to stop responding when this is running.

I tried to implement a background worker to take the strain off of the UI. I moved the recursive method's code over to the `Do_Work` event and called it with `RunWorkerAsync` but it crashed, reporting the following:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.
```

What's the best way of moving the code away from the UI? I'm not very familiar with background workers so I may be doing it wrong.

Comment: You can use a background worker, just use `Invoke(new Action<string>(SendKeys.Send), keys)` to dispatch the call on the UI thread.

Comment: BGW isn't going to help you here.  BGW exists to move long running, **CPU bound**, *non-UI* tasks to another thread.  You have a long running *IO bound*, *UI* operation on your hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case for `async`.  Try replacing `Thread.Sleep()` with `Task.Delay()`.

```
async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await SendMyKeysAsync();
}

async Task SendMyKeysAsync()
{
    while (thePixelIsStillRed)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("whatever");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

This approach leaves the UI thread free to continue pumping messages during the delay period, without spawning any additional threads.

Comment: There isn't really any reason to make this method recursive.  You're just notably increasing the resource consumption and using a non-idiomatic pattern for no real reason.

Comment: @Servy OP claims method calls itself recursively this way; method is just staying true to that. Not saying it's a good idea though

Comment: Turns out async was just what I needed. Thanks for that @piedar it has taken the strain off of the UI. Not sure why recursiveness would be a bad idea for this but it's getting the job done for me.

Comment: @Chrayfish If recursion goes too deep, you'll eventually get a `StackOverflowException` from running out of stack space.  For a simple method, this will probably only happen after many thousands of calls (and the compiler might help you out [under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571052/1925996)), but it's usually best to avoid C# recursion if possible.

Comment: @Chrayfish A recursive `async` method has dramatically more resource consumption than a non-async method, as you're rebuilding the entire state machine of the method on every iteration.  And again, it's very much non-idiomatic code in C#.  It's not even an operation that conceptually makes sense as a recursive operation; it's not how most people are going to think of such a problem.

Comment: It will need to run potentially 1000s of times until the exiting condition is true. What would be the best route to take with this?

Comment: Since we agree that recursion is not a good approach here, I removed the recursive example to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a synchronous recursive method, you should write an asynchronous iterative method.

```
private async void Foo()
{
    while(ShouldKeepLooping())
    {
        SendKeys.Send(keyToSend);
        await Task.Delay(timespan.FromSeconds(2));
    }
}
```

Making the method recursive adds nothing; making it iterative removes stack pressure.  By making the method asynchronous, rather than synchronous, you don't block the UI thread.